# Azure: managing multiple VMs in the same availability set

Tags: ubuntu, azure, ssh, virtual-machine

Recently I learned that it is not advised to use a single VM to run my server applications because Microsoft can take this VM offline when updating causing my services to be unavailable for some time.

Instead Microsoft advises to use multiple VMs and place these in the same cloud service and availability set. Microsoft will ensure at least one VM will stay online while updating. (Correct me if I am wrong so far).

Like I said I currently only use one VM. I use git to deploy updates of my applications and I can simply use SSH to check if everything on the VM is running as expected. I also locally run a DB so everything is self contained which is easy to manage. The VM I use is a simple Ubuntu 14.10 server.

How would this work when I have multiple VMs? Would I need to log in using SSH to every server to make a change? Would I also need to push to several git repositories in order to update my application? How would this work if one of the VMs is offline (due to the scaling settings which I want to use)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this question is more of a "What's your opinion on what I should do?" There are a number of ways you can solve this problem. I am going to personally suggest that you take a look at Puppet or Chef to handle your deployments. This allows you to manage code and configuration by way of "recipes".

If a configuration is changed outside of the "recipe" they will get rolled back.
If a server is offline, when it comes back up, the deployment server will see there needs to be an update and will automatically catch the server up.
If you deploy a third (or fourth) server, you simply configure the new server with the master server for configuration, and the server will be made duplicate to the other servers.

Comment: Interesting! This does look like what I need. And you are right I am interested in the opinions and (arguably) best practices of experienced Azure users.